# Retrieving business information using LinkedIn API

Tags: android, ios, linkedin-api

I am working on an app in which customer has requested us to support login using LinkedIn and retrieve his business information from linked.

More specifically I want to retrieve these informations with respect to his business:

1. Business Name
2. Business Phone
3. Business Address
4. Postal Code
5. City
6. State
7. Business Established Date
8. Type of business
9. Company Structure
10. Tax ID Number

I know that I can allow user to login using his LinkedIn credentials, but I am skeptical about retrieving all or any of the info specified above

Does linkedIn API provide all or any of this info?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn seems to support getting most of this information for a company. You need the logged in LinkedIn user to be the administrator of this company's profile on LinkedIn to authorize your application to get the data. Then you can retrieve the company profile fields listed here:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/company-profile

It seems that fields 1-7 in your list are covered, Tax ID Number is not. I am not sure about Type of Business, there is a "company type" field returned by LinkedIn, I don't know if this is what you need. Regarding Company Structure, depends on what you mean.

With the account of any LinkedIn employee of the company (who is not an administrator) you can retrieve a much smaller list of fields:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/companies